# Neo4j Cypher count query performance optimizaztion

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have the following Neo4j Cypher count() query:

```
MATCH (dg:DecisionGroup)-[:CONTAINS]->(childD:Decision) 
WHERE dg.id = 1 
MATCH (childD)-[relationshipValueRel4:HAS_VALUE_ON]-(filterCharacteristic4:Characteristic) 
WHERE filterCharacteristic4.id = 4 
WITH relationshipValueRel4, childD, dg 
WHERE  (ANY (id IN [5, 25, 106] WHERE id IN relationshipValueRel4.optionIds ))  
WITH childD, dg  
RETURN count(childD) as total
```

Right now this query works pretty slow:

Cypher version: CYPHER 3.3, planner: COST, runtime: INTERPRETED. 3380782 total db hits in 2991 ms.

This is PROFILE output:

[image]

How to optimize this query performance ?

**P.S**

The corresponding main query works pretty fast:

```
PROFILE MATCH (dg:DecisionGroup)-[:CONTAINS]->(childD:Decision) 
WHERE dg.id = 1 
MATCH (childD)-[relationshipValueRel4:HAS_VALUE_ON]-(filterCharacteristic4:Characteristic) 
WHERE filterCharacteristic4.id = 4 
WITH relationshipValueRel4, childD, dg 
WHERE  (ANY (id IN [5, 25, 106] 
WHERE id IN relationshipValueRel4.optionIds ))  
WITH childD, dg  WITH childD , dg  
SKIP 0 LIMIT 10 
WITH * 
MATCH (childD)-[ru:CREATED_BY]->(u:User) 
OPTIONAL MATCH (childD)-[rup:UPDATED_BY]->(up:User)  
RETURN ru, u, rup, up, childD AS decision, 
[ (dg)<-[:DEFINED_BY]-(entity)<-[:COMMENTED_ON]-(comg:CommentGroup)-[:COMMENTED_FOR]->(childD) | {entityId: toInt(entity.id),  types: labels(entity), totalComments: toInt(comg.totalComments)} ] AS commentGroups, 
[ (dg)<-[:DEFINED_BY]-(c1)<-[vg1:HAS_VOTE_ON]-(childD) | {criterionId: toInt(c1.id),  weight: vg1.avgVotesWeight, totalVotes: toInt(vg1.totalVotes)} ] AS weightedCriteria, [ (dg)<-[:DEFINED_BY]-(ch1:Characteristic)<-[v1:HAS_VALUE_ON]-(childD)  WHERE  NOT ((ch1)<-[:DEPENDS_ON]-())  | {characteristicId: toInt(ch1.id),  optionIds: v1.optionIds, valueIds: v1.valueIds, value: v1.value, available: v1.available, totalHistoryValues: v1.totalHistoryValues, totalFlags: v1.totalFlags, description: v1.description, valueType: ch1.valueType, visualMode: ch1.visualMode} ] AS valuedCharacteristics
```

Cypher version: CYPHER 3.3, planner: COST, runtime: INTERPRETED. 11725 total db hits in 8 ms

[image]

Please help to optimize the `count()` query performance also.