# Neo4j index on relationship property

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Is it possible in Neo4j to create an index on relationship property? Right now I faced a very poor performance over comparison/filtering operations on relationship property value. This is the example of my issue [Neo4j Cypher count query performance optimizaztion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47749396/neo4j-cypher-count-query-performance-optimizaztion)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In neo4j 3.3.x, there are now built-in procedures for [explicit indexes](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.3/cypher/schema/index/#explicit-indexes-procedures), which include the ability to create "explicit" indexes for relationships.

"Explicit" indexes are not the same as the normal "schema" indexes that you are already aware of (which are automatically maintained for you once you create an index or uniqueness constraint). They are called "explicit" because you have to write code to add nodes or relationships to such indexes, and you also have to write code to get nodes or relationships from such indexes. But, it might be worth the effort in some cases.